# Get timezoned offset date objects using moment.js

Tags: javascript, timezone, momentjs

I am trying to get the timestamp in milliseconds for two timezones (New York and Sydney), and use them in a jquery clock, to show relative to local time. I am using moment.js and moment-timezone.js.

This gives me the correct moment for NY:

```
moment().tz("America/New_York")
```

I know this as format() returns the correct NY time as a string.

```
2015-04-04T12:52:51-04:00
```

I now want the timestamp correctly offset, so when I put it into the clock with

```
$("#clock").clock({"timestamp":customtimestamp});
```

It displays NY time. However, if I, naively, use

```
moment().tz("America/New_York").valueOf()
```

and put that in the clock, it returns my local time.

So how do I show the NY time correctly in the clock using my moment object?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I am far from sure of myself on this one.  I came up with a solution which I think does what you want, but I am not happy with how 'hacky' it looks.

The following seems to be ok for me at the command line. From what I understand of the JQuery clock you use, you should be able to use to value show in the console log (basically the local unix time plus the zone offset, which is negative in this case):

```
var moment = require( 'moment-timezone' ),
    nytz = moment.tz( "America/New_York" ),
    asstring = nytz.format(),
    asunixtime = parseInt( nytz.format( 'X' ) ),
    offset = moment.parseZone( asstring ).utcOffset();

console.log( asunixtime + offset );
```

Way too hacky to be a valid answer, I am afraid, but I am stumped to do it properly with moment API.

One last thing: if you run in a browser make sure you have the timezone data (see [here](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/use-it/browser/)).

Hope it helps a bit.

Comment: Thanks for the help - most appreciated. I ended up not calculating the offsets at all in JS, I used server side python. Timezone aware date objects in JS = total nightmare.